# unistd.h is not available, How to use fork()

Tags: c, fork, dos, dosbox

I want to exercise some UNIX commands using C language. When I include `<unistd.h>` header file and when I use `fork()` method it gives me a compile time error: `"can not include unistd.h"`. I check on he Internet and the `fork()` method is available in `<unistd.h>` header file only. Please help me on this.

- Is now `<unistd.h>` is replaced with any other header file?
- Even if I use `"process.h"`, that does not have a definition for `fork()`.
- How I can use `fork()` method?

I have DOSBox v0.74 on my system (Windows 7, 64-bit).

Comment: Can you show your error? Can you provide more context?

Comment: Does DOSBox provide `<unistd.h>`?  Does it document its presence?  If not, maybe try [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) instead; that does provide a `fork()` emulation and `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: Neither DOSBox nor Windows have a native `fork` function, and as neither is a Unix variant they of course doesn't have the `<unistd.h>` header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) web site says it is an emulation of DOS for Unix machines, not an emulator of Unix for Windows (DOS) machines.  You need [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or something similar if you want to emulate Unix on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way of emulating fork() on win32 or dos.

Comment: True, but Cygwin provides a decent approximation to `fork()` for Windows.

Comment: But this isn't Windows; it's DOS, and DOS is fundamentally incapable of performing a `fork` operation.

Comment: The host environment is Windows 7.  It can run Cygwin, which provides a decent Unix emulation on Windows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler DOSBox is an emulator running in the host environment. The code run in the emulator does not have access to Cygwin `fork` ;-)

Comment: So, as I indicated in my answer, DOSBox is the wrong tool for the job of running Unix code on a Windows machine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yeah, well-told!

Comment: There is no way you would want to use such a primitive, obscure function in windows anyway, where you have CreateProcess() and similar better functions, that lead to smaller executables, less RAM consumption and less obscure code.

Comment: @Lundin but in the DOS we have nothing :)

Comment: Actually, DOS or at least some libc such as Turbo C's had fork... but it had semantics like vfork(), parent would halt until child was done.

Comment: @fasked No, because DOS was not a real OS, since it didn't support multiple processes. So it _really_ doesn't make any sense whatsoever to use fork() in DOS.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Sounds like a real useless function. Why couldn't an if statement be used instead?

Comment: @Lundin, Useless or not, it was there. Actually, it was quite useful for calling separate binaries and then returning back to your app whence the separate program was done. But this is all incidental, the OP likely needs Cygwin or something.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant But if there were separate binaries, it doesn't sound like a fork() as it is spec:ed in *nix, but rather as something similar to Windows' CreateProcess()?

Comment: @Lundin, it was the old fork+exec combo

Answer (score 0):

You always can declare anything yourself:
    pid_t fork(void);
However, if your system don't have unistd.h, it isn't POSIX compliant (or you haven't installed headers at all).

Comment: `fork` is wrapper over a system call, and you can't fully compile the code without `fork` being resolved at link-time...

Comment: How to make is POSIX compliant?

Comment: @Rahul.G well, you can't... unless you implement all of POSIX or find a working implementation by someone else.

Comment: Ofc you have to link with libc's fork to mate it working, but still - it exactly what header files do. And... Ouch, it's DOS... That was confusing. What it have to do with unix, anyhow?